# Passing list of data from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to retrieve data in a specific order (to establish a ranking) with the below code:

```
public ActionResult ShowRanking(int id = 0)
        {
            Tournament tournament = db.Tournament.Find(id);

            var parti = (from p in db.Participe
                        where p.IdTournament == tournament.IdTournament
                        //orderby p.ArchTotalScore descending
                        select p).OrderByDescending(x => x.ArchTotalScore);

            //objlist = parti;

            foreach (var part in parti)
            {
                tournament.Participe.Add(part);

                //objlist.Add(part);

            }
            tournament.Participe.OrderByDescending(x => x.ArchTotalScore);

            return View(tournament.Participe);
        }
```

The data is retrieved but whenever I pass the list ofdata to my view, the order criterias I used are ignored and the records are shown as they have been inserted in the DB.

Here is my view as well:

```
@model ArcheryComp.Tournament

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Classement";
}

<h2>Classement</h2>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nom
            </th>
            <th>
                Prenom
            </th>
            <th>
                Division
            </th>
            <th>
                Categorie
            </th>
            <th>
                Score 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Score 2
            </th>
            <th>
                Total Score
            </th>
        </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Participe)
    {

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Archers.Nom)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Archers.Prenom)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Divisions.DivDescription)
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Categorie)
                    </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArchScore1)
                    </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArchScore2)
                    </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArchTotalScore)
                    </td>
                    <br />
                </tr>
                var tmp = item.IdTournament;
            }

    </table>
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong ? and could I correct this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: tournument.participate is what?list,hashset

Comment: You need to set your result to the result of OrderByDescending and return that.

Comment: @dustmouse is right, OrderByDescending doesnt modify the original list, it only returns a new ordered version.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback all !! @dustmouse how can I set my results to the results of OrderByDescending?

Comment: @DavidE, Are you using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ordered the `tournament.Participe`, but you did not use the result. You must change it to something like this(if `tournament.Participe` is a `List`ofcourse):

```
tournament.Participe = 
       tournament.Participe.OrderByDescending(x => x.ArchTotalScore).ToList();
return View(tournament);
```

The model used in the view is `ArcheryComp.Tournament` therefore you must return `View(tournament)` not `View(tournament.Participe)`.